# Get Max value and corresponding column

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

How can I get corresponding columns from a max query in mysql?  I want find out how many wins a player has.  I will find that out by doing a count of the number of games that player has won.  The will be done by selecting the max value per game and resulting player_id.  However I am not sure how to get the corresponding player_id.

I have

```
   id   |   game_id | player_id | score

    1   |     1     |     1     |   254
    2   |     1     |     2     |   194
    3   |     2     |     1     |   432
    4   |     2     |     2     |   298
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This query should get what you need:

```
SELECT
    player_id, game_id, score
FROM
(
    SELECT game_id,MAX(score) AS MaxScore
    FROM games
    GROUP BY game_id
) AS Winners
JOIN games
    ON (games.game_id = Winners.game_id AND games.score = Winners.MaxScore)
```

It assumes that a tie is a win for both players.

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/658e9/3)

If you want to get just the player and their number of wins, you can use this query:

```
SELECT
    player_id, COUNT(*) AS wins
FROM
(
    SELECT game_id,MAX(score) AS MaxScore
    FROM games
    GROUP BY game_id
) AS Winners
JOIN games
    ON (games.game_id = Winners.game_id AND games.score = Winners.MaxScore)
WHERE player_id = {player_id}
GROUP BY player_id
```

Just replace `{player_id}` with the player you're looking for and `wins` is their number of wins or ties.

Comment: thank you. This works.  I cannot believe how complicated it is to get something simple!

Comment: I think I completely misunderstood the the results desired. You are right about my score misapplication. +1 for getting it right for the OP.

Comment: How could I edit it to show the number of wins and losses?  No its ok, I'll just make it a min instead and count that and have them both as subqueries

Comment: @Nicola Yeah, you can just add another subquery, but you'll need to do some other modifications, too, to get both wins and losses in one query.

Comment: ahh, I wonder if I would be better redoing my schema.  What do you think?

Comment: You can make the SQL query a tad simpler by removing `player_id` from the inner `SELECT` statements.

Comment: @nicola Maybe.  I can't immediately think of a significantly better way to do it, but you might find something by playing around with it.

Comment: @unutbu That is correct; the `player_id` in the subquery isn't used and I don't remember why I put it there.  I'm updating my answer.

Comment: I have another question  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437661/get-game-id-of-a-players-maxscore-in-sql) which is related to this question if you are interested

Comment: I wish this were possible:  `SELECT max(field) as max_field, max(if(field = max(field)), field2, NULL) as max_field2` - unfortunately referencing aggregate like that is not allowed.  Maybe someday...