# Get game_id of a players MAX(score) in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

This is a follow on from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15418496/get-max-value-and-corresponding-column/15419084?noredirect=1#comment21829964_15419084) question.

I want to get the game id that a player had his maximum score in.  I am struggling to get the corresponding game_id column value when selecting the max(score)

My table is as follows:

```
id    game_id    player_id    score
1       1            1         345
2       1            2         234
3       2            1         190
4       2            2         167
5       3            4         230
6       3            1         230
7       4            2         453
8       4            3         230
```

My query looks like this so far:

```
SELECT s.id, t.game_id, t.score
FROM    (
        SELECT game_id, score
        FROM stats
        WHERE player_id =2
    ) t
LEFT JOIN stats s on s.game_id = t.game_id AND s.score = t.score
WHERE s.player_id = 2
```

This gives me

```
id    game_id    score
 2        1       234
 4        2       167
 7        4       453
```

I then need to join this whole query on as a subquery on the maximum score (id = 7), in order to then get the game_id, but I am not sure how to say join on this maximum value

Comment: I should say I need it for one user, not all users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here i have created [sql feedle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cdaa4/13) you can remove

```
SELECT s.id, t.game_id, t.score
FROM    (
        SELECT game_id, score
        FROM game
        WHERE player_id =2 order by score desc limit 0,1
    ) t
LEFT JOIN game s on s.game_id = t.game_id AND s.score = t.score
```

Comment: Thank you, this is much simpler than grouping by and selecting max

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    TableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  player_ID, MAX(Score) max_score
            FROM    TableName
            GROUP   BY Player_ID
        ) b ON a.Player_ID = b.player_ID AND
                a.Score = b.max_score
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this can help you.

```
    select game_id, player_id, score 
    from (
         select rank() over (partition by player_id order by score desc) as rank_id, game_id, player_id, score
         from stats
         ) a
    where rank_id=1 and player_id = 2
```